# Opposite of BGREWRITEAOF?

Tags: redis

I am wanting to configure in-memory REDIS Master with a Slave providing the persistence to AOF and RDB.

In the event of a crash or reboot, is there an easy way to reload the in-memory master? To load from the AOF provided by the Slave instance?

Thanks

Comment: This might have been better called "Opposite of BGSAVE", thanks again.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am asking for help running REDIS in Windows Server 2012 as an in-memory "master" database, with a "slave" backup saving changes to AOF and/or RDB disk files.